# Is there a shorter, better and optimised way to fill this list from SQL database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I got this code and it works without problems. But i sense there is much better way to do this.

```
    namespace Repositories
    {
        public class AuthorRepository : IAuthorRepository
        {
            public List<Author> GetAllFromRepo()
            {
                using (AppContext myDB = new AppContext())
                {
                    List<Author> authorsFromRepo = new List<Author>();
                    foreach (var item in myDB.Authors)
                    {
                        authorsFromRepo.Add(new Author()
                        {
                            Books = new List<Book>(),
                            ID = item.ID,
                            FirstName = item.FirstName,
                            LastName = item.LastName
                        });
                    }
                    return authorsFromRepo.ToList();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When i try something along the lines of this:

```
 public List<Author> GetAllFromRepo()
    {
        using (AppContext myDB = new AppContext())
        {
            List<Author> authorsFromRepo = new List<Author>();

            authorsFromRepo = myDB.Authors.ToList();
            return authorsFromRepo;
        }
    }
```

I always get this error:

> Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: source
>   Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: source
>   Source Error: Line 33: return authors.Select(x => new AuthorViewModel()

Any Help?
The model where the error takes me

```
namespace Services
{
    public class AuthorService : IAuthorService
    {
        private readonly IAuthorRepository _AuthorRepository;

        public AuthorService(IAuthorRepository authorRepository)
        {
            _AuthorRepository = authorRepository;
        }
        public List<AuthorViewModel> GetAll()
        {
            List<Author> authors = _AuthorRepository.GetAllFromRepo();

            return authors.Select(x => new AuthorViewModel()
            {
                ID = x.ID,
                FullName = $"{x.FirstName } {x.LastName} ",
                Books = x.Books.Select(g => new BookViewModel()
                {
                    ID = g.ID,
                    Name = g.Name
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

To add again, everything works fine if i use the first example of code.
When i try something shorter like

```
 return myDB.Authors.ToList();
```

i get the error.

when i change to:

```
return authors.Select(x => new AuthorViewModel()
       {
        ID = x.ID,
        FullName = $"{x.FirstName } {x.LastName} ",
        Books = {}
        }).ToList();
```

It works then... but this means it doesn't read the author books...

Comment: Your error refers to `AuthorViewModel` - what is that model? - all hat should be necessary is one line of code - `return myDB.Authors.ToList();`

Comment: I thought so also but i still have the same error. Here is the Model btw,

Comment: Is `authors` in `List<Author> authors = _AuthorRepository.GetAllFromRepo();` `null`?

Comment: Or is `Books` in `x.Books` `null`?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I wrote the error that appears in browser.

Comment: The message suggests that either one of the variables I noted in the previous 2 comments is `null` - debug you code and check (you may need to use `return myDB.Authors.Include(x => x.Books).ToList();`

Comment: Because in the first code you are doing `Books = new List<Book>(),` and that's not there in second code. So you are getting error because `x.Books` is null.

Comment: Yes, x.Books is null. That helped me a Lot. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the model for Authors to

```
namespace Entities
{
    public class Author
    {
        // this is what a had to add here
        // From here
        public Author()
        {
            Books = new List<Book>();
        }
        // to here

        public int   ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So It wont give me any errors when x.Books is null.

Comment: HM! Check the specification of`Author.Books`, If your specification says that a NULL value means something different than "Author did not write any books", for instance: "don't know about his books", then you should not change it into: "this Author didn't write any books". Getting rid of your exception does not mean that you solved the error. If  a NULL return is specified equal to an empty list, why do you ever allow that Author.Books equals null?  In LINQ it is usually better not to return NULL when an IEnumerable is expected but return `Enumerable.Empty<Book>()`